# What is the most memory efficient way to add multiple columns from different dataframes together?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some very large dataframes and often run out of memory when I want to combine them via a weighted sum.

So what I am doing now is:

```
dfA[col] = dfA[col]*wA dfB[col]*wB + dfC[col]*wC + dfD[col]*wD
```

Where `wA` is the weight of the A-th dataframe.
I run out of memory 4 out of 5 times, so I wonder how I could do this with the smallest possible memory footprint?

I tried adding them one by one.
i.e.

```
dfA[col] = dfA[col]*wA
dfA[col] += dfB[col]*wB
...
```

this ran out of memory 100% of the time for the same dataframes.

Should I iterate over the rows and use `iloc`?
Do it in numpy and convert back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may help to use pandas `eval`:

```
pd.eval("dfA[col] * wA + dfB[col] * wB + dfC[col] * wC + dfD[col] * wD")
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253145/discussion-on-answer-by-pauls-what-is-the-most-memory-efficient-way-to-add-multi); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is already aligned, using the underlying numpy arrays might also be more efficient:

```
dfA[col] = (dfA[col].to_numpy()*wA
           +dfB[col].to_numpy()*wB
           +dfC[col].to_numpy()*wC
           +dfD[col].to_numpy()*wD
           )
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it is aligned, I'll try this, to help my understanding, why is converting each to numpy more efficient? because the multiplication and addition is done in numpy?

Comment: Because numpy arrays are more lightweight than pandas Series, but you have to test with your data it's always hard to optimize without a real example. In the end if your data is just too big to fit in memory, this will also fail ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for elaborating, I am actually runnning the experiment right now.
It is probably right on the edge, as it fails sometimes but not always.

Comment: In addition, check [pandas tips to work with data that is larger than memory](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/scale.html). If this still fails, you might need to use other libraries (this is also covered in the link)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data you have, you can consider saving memory by downcasting your numeric columns into datatypes requiring less memory.

[By default](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html?highlight=basics#defaults), pandas stores numeric data as `int64` and `float64` respectively. You can change the type either by:

- using [astype()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) if the data is already numeric
- (probably not your case) or using [to_numeric()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `downcast` if you need to convert it to a numeric value first

Only do this, **IF** the datatype you are downcasting to is sufficient to represent your data, as to avoid any data loss.